# Prevent location.hash "jumping" in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Is there a way to prevent the window location hash from causing the document to "jump" in IE10? The code below solves for both Chrome and Firefox.

```
if (location.hash) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }, 1);
}
```

As a note, I've also tried this with jQuery's `$(window)` as well, but with no luck.

Comment: Why use hash if you do not want the page to scroll?

Comment: I am linking to a specific tab from another page – I would like the user to access the content inside of that tab, but without being forced down the page where the tab/hash is located (in the left navigation, halfway down the page). The content starts above where the hash lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After meeting with Lauren, we determined:

- `window.scrollTo(0,0)` works in IE 10 by opening developer tools and running the command. So we knew the code works in isolation but there was something else we were doing wrong or that there was code on the page preventing the page from going to the top.
- As a quick hack, we incremented the interval from 1 millisecond to 2000 milliseconds to see if it was a race condition. This *worked* but not desirable due to the page flicker/jumping. We brought the value down from 2000 milliseconds to a lower value to minimize the flicker effect.
- Page wouldn't scroll to the top only when first going to the page from a different route, not just reloading the page... perhaps some other JavaScript on the page causing different logic paths.

Thoughts:

- Perhaps only happened in IE10 due to slow JavaScript execution. Other browsers parse and interpret JavaScript faster.
- Scroll could be removed via query parameters instead of anchors but would cause code to be refactored and not so pretty url paths. i.e. `https://<url>?tab-name=TabNameToSelect`
- Scroll could be removed via server side or client side routing but would require larger development effort... routes could have pattern like `{controller}/{action}/{tab-id}` or `{controller}/{action}/{item-id}/{tab-id}`

Quick fix solution:

```
// quick and dirty franken'fix
if (location.hash) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }, 250);   // increment interval to "prevent" race condition
}
```